# Change format of DateTime object in c# and store back as DateTime object

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I want to convert string  2017-03-05 to Datetime object in c# in format
yyyy-MM-dd

```
string startDate = "2017-03-05"; 
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> myDate gives me 05-03-2017 00:00:00

But I want myDate DateTime object like 2017-03-05 00:00:00 i.e yyyy-MM-dd format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you parse your string to DateTime, it will have *no* format.

DateTime structure does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values which is based on long field as [`Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks). Format concept *only* applies when you try to get it's *textual* (aka string) representation of it. It is really important to understand the difference between a DateTime instance and it's formatted string representation.

So, if you wanna get a specific textual format of your DateTime, you will need to get it's string representation again.

```
string result = myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```