# Converting string to DateTime while deserializing

Tags: c#, .net

I have an json like this

```
[{"date":"2019-04-03(13:43)","storyid":"123363},{""date":"2019-04-03(09:02)","storyid":"123555"},{"date":"2019-04-03(08:44)","storyid":"664224"}]
```

and I am deserializing the json to a list of NewsHeadlines like this using c# and .net framework..

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewsHeadline>>(json);
```

This works as expected and its just that I want a DateTime property called Date in a specific format ("yyyy-MM-dd(HH:mm)"). I could change the format of the datetime after deserilaizing but I am keen to know if there is a way to change it in the get set level.. Can someone help me understand how to do this?

```
    [DataMember(Name = "date")]
    public DateTime Date {get;set}

    [DataMember(Name = "storyid")]
    public string StoryId {get; set;}
```

so the end result can be Date (DateTime object) with value 2019-04-03(13:43)

Comment: `DateTime` objects do not have a format.  They are a structure.  They only have a format when written to a string.

Comment: What if you make a string property that holds the value of “2019-04-03 (13:43)” and make another property (with getter only) and this property convert the value of string to datetime .

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606367/change-format-of-datetime-object-in-c-sharp-and-store-back-as-datetime-object

Answer (score 2):

```cs
    public class MyDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
    {
        public MyDateTimeConverter()
        {
            //Take care of the format here 
            base.DateTimeFormat ="yyyy-MM-dd(HH:mm)";
        }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[DataMember(name="Date")]
private string Date_asString
{
    get
    {
        return Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd(HH:mm)");
    }
    set
    {
        Date = DateTime.Parse(value);
    }
 }
```

Given that you are using [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) and datacontract serializers.